# Symfony/Doctrine ManyToMany in the order the are assigned

Tags: php, symfony, join, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I have an entity called `Game` which has a `ManyToMany` connection with a `JoinTable` to an entity called `Question`

This works pretty well. The problem is, that I need the questions in the exact order as they are chosen, not sorted by question id, as I get them now when I call `getQuestions()` on the `Game` class.
Is there a way to do that?

The Questions are all added with `$game->addQuestion($question);`. The Questions are existing, the game is persisted, after the questions are added.

```
...
class Game {
    ...
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Question")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="Games_to_Questions",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="game_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="question_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     **/
    private $questions;
    ...
}
...
class Question {
    ...
}
...
```

Comment: What do you mean with "they are chosen"?

Comment: The user can drag and drop the questions and sort them. When he/she chooses question (id) 55, 30 and 70, then I want to display them in that order. They are added in that order, but when I call them later (on a different request) they are ordered 30, 55, 70

Comment: OK. why don't you add a field named "sorting_order" AMD use doctrine2 sort facility?

Comment: Where would I have to add that field? to the join table or the questions? Questions can be used in multiple Games, so therefore can't use a sort field on the question.

Comment: You can add an extra tabel with "game" field that wi ode rify your game and .... Magic baby :)

Comment: Derick F answer is what i suggested in my comments ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you're going to have to add an intermediary entity with a sort order column.  Let's call it GameQuestion.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="game_question")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Gedmo\Sortable\Entity\Repository\SortableRepository")
 */
class GameQuestion {
    private $game;
    private $question;
    /**
     * @Gedmo\SortablePosition
     */
    private $sortOrder;
}
```

Comment: damn! I was writing this! The correct aswer, why? Because a join table is converted in an entity when you need store additional data like in this case: `$sortOrder`

Comment: This answer is what I've said into comment :) Nice way to copy, rep-hunter! :)

Comment: Didn't know about the Gedmo Sortable stuff yet, that looks pretty nice! but as I've understood it from the docs (https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/sortable.md), I should make `$game` the `SortableGroup` otherwise it will be a sort list over all joins, not just the one's per game.